# How to navigate through values in x4000 -x400A and check whether or not they are 1 or 0

Tags: assembly, lc3

I have digits stored in x4000 through x400A and I need to see if they have the value of 0 or 1. I have tried using

```
LEA R1, BOB
LDR R6, R1, #0
BRp Break
ADD R6, R6 #1

BOB .FILL x4000
```

But that only returns the x4000 value that it starts on.

Comment: You need an algorithm, it will be simple and involve a loop. You don't have to think in assembly to figure out an algorithm.  Loops exist in most languages, so write in one that does the job even if in pseudo code, for example. Once you know what you want the code to do, then study how to take an algorithm to assembly by translating for-loop and if-then statements, lots of posts on those here.

Comment: You put the address in `R1` so you should increment that register.  And of course it has to be in a loop, so you need a backwards branch.  Also, check that `ldr` sets FLAGS; in most ISAs loads/stores don't.  If so you'd want something like `add r6, r6, #0` to set FLAGS according to the register value.

Comment: @PeterCordes, the condition codes are set by LC-3's loads, even including LEA for some unknown reason.  The only instructions that don't set them are branches/jumps and stores.